# Can "who" be used to start a predicative clause

Tags: grammar

I'm an ESL student and trying to writing a paper but I don't know should I use "are those who" or "are who" in this sentence.

> Although the literature suggested that there are controversies on how
>   to define ecotourists, the ecotourists in this study are (those?) who
>   report they are interested in ecotourism by themselves.

I had tried to search in the COCA corpus, and I found "are those who" is used commonly used. But I still confused why "are who" is not correct.

I searched the wikipedia and it has an example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression "That is when it happens." It explained "when it happens" is a predicative clause. So I'm still confused can "who" be used to start a predicative clause? Why "are who" is not correct?

Comment: You must include "those". It is the antecedent for "who" in the relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks. I'm wondering where is wrong if the "who report they ..." is considered as an object clause? Can it be considered as an object clause that "who report they..." is the object for "ecotourists are ..."? Why/Why can't

Comment: No, because the verb "be" doesn't take objects -- only transitive verbs can do that.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks so much. I understand be can't take objects. But I'm still confused... I searched the wikipedia and it has an example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression "That is when it happens." It explained "when it happens" is a predicative clause (not what I think was an object clause...). So I'm still confused can "who" be used to start a predicative clause? Why "are who" is not correct?

Comment: Start by eliminating most of that. Doesn’t *Ecotourists are (those) who are interested in ecotourism* illustrate the same problem more clearly?

Drop *who are*.

Losing *those* would make *Ecotourists are interested in ecotourism* define or explain who the ecotourists were, not count them.

Restoring *those* would let *Ecotourists are those interested in ecotourism* count the ecotourists, however they were defined.

Comment: It used to be able to: _Who steals my purse steals trash_ (Hamlet). But not now, though it can of course head an embedded question: _I never find out who steals my purse_.